# Question regarding the IQR

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, mean, median, interquartile

I have a question regarding some homework for uni:

The variable "number of points per game" has a mean of 25, a median of 30, and an interquartile range of 20. Which of the following statements are certainly correct?

Select one or more:

a.
Exactly 25 percent of all games have less than 20 points

b.
50 percent of all games have more than 30 points

c.
The distribution of 'points per game' is positively skewed

I know that b is correct, and c is wrong. However, I am super unsure about a. Thank you in advance!

Best,
Paula

Comment: Are you sure about (b)? What if this median is based on a finite sample of an odd number of games? See the Wikipedia entry on [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Finite_data_set_of_numbers). For (a), the IQR tells you how far apart the 25th and 75th percentiles are. Does that tell you anything about the _location_ of the 25th percentile?

Comment: Even if it's an infinite population distribution, exactly 30 will be sure to have nonzero probability (this is basketball), so if the median is uniquely 30 then less than half the distribution will be strictly above 30, so strictly b is not "certainly correct" then either.

Comment: With these kind of questions, I find it best to sketch a picture of how you think the probability distribution with the prescribed properties might look. It’s much more natural to look at a picture than mentally hold mean, median and IQR values in your head.